# What is the difference between "MK-V" and standard parts?

Tags: dead-space-3

"MK-V" aren't found on levels and must be purchased in resource packs either with real money or ration seals. All MK-V components have their "basic" counterparts with identical in-game description.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premium currency MK-V parts are an (even stronger) alternative to MK-II upgrade parts that can be found in-game. They have a variety of effects, but always provide some sort of benefit:

> Mk. II tips have a green and silver/chrome finish while Mk. V versions have a blue and gold finish. These improved versions (Mk. II) provide varying benefits such as a faster rate of fire, a larger ammo capacity, or increased damage, depending on the weapon. Mk. V variants provide an even further boost within the same areas as their Mk. II counterparts.

Attaching one will also add 'Overclocked' to your weapon's name.

(Source: [Dead Space Wiki's page on weapons](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Space_3_Weapons).)

Comment: I wonder why the title is misspelled  on the Wikia page? I visited the page, but didn't find the title MK-V with search.